# Adding the mapbox wordmark to leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, attribution

I am using mapbox on my leaflet map so I need to add the mapbox wordmark to it. For some reason I cannot find the watermark file itself. I looked here for example

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/attribution/

but I could not find the file. Where do I get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the attribution documentation you linked, take a closer look at the [Other mapping frameworks](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/attribution/#other-mapping-frameworks) section describing how to insert the proper attribution. The example given by Mapbox uses a `background-image` property with a data URL to display the image:

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64, [...]
```

For example, as an isolated element :

```css
.mapbox-wordmark {
    height: 20px;
    width: 65px;

    /* `background-image` contains the Mapbox wordmark */
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: 65px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='mapbox-wordmark'></div>
```